# Using variables in a for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I understand the magic of the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`; this brought me one step further but I am still not completely happy. I  am now able to assign the filename to a `!loop variable!`, but I fail to use that variable subseqently. I try to get the filename without the extension. There must be something else that I am unaware of.

This is my coding now:

```
::process all files in directory
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%f in (C:\windows\*.ico) do (

    echo F=%%f
    set myname=%%f
    echo.N=!myname!
    call :strlen myLen "!myname!"
    echo.myLen=!myLen!

    set /A L=myLen-3 + 1
    set str=!myname!
    echo.str1=!str! L=!L!
    set str=!str:~0,!L! !    <-Remove extension from filename
    echo.str2=!str!          <-This does not work!
```

)

Here is the output of my call :

```
 F=C:\windows\AnyWeb Print.ico
 N=C:\windows\AnyWeb Print.ico
 Strlen C:\windows\AnyWeb Print.ico
 myLen=25
 str1=C:\windows\AnyWeb Print.ico L=23
 str2=L       <--- what went wrong ????
```

Comment: Honestly, learn powershell. Then you won't have to keep on doing what I like to call cmd gymnastics, twisting yourself in knots trying to bend a basically deficient language to your needs :-)

Comment: Why don't you use [`~`-modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of the `for` meta-variable, like `%%~Nf` to get the base name and `%%~Xf` to get the extension, for instance? *N. B.:* [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line

```
set str=!str:~0,!L! !    <-Remove extension from filename
```

The exclamation marks are used from left to right, you get two parts

`set str=!str:~0,!` and  `L! !`

This could be solved by using a different form of expansion, like FOR-loop-parameter, like

```
for %%X in (!L!) DO set str=!str:~0,%%X!
```

But in your case there exist a much simpler solution

```
for %%C in (C:\windows\*.ico) do (

  set myname=%%C
  set name_without_extension=%%~nC
  echo Name=!myname!
  echo Only Name=!name_without_extension!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the general case,

```
CALL set str=%%str:~0,!L!%%
```

This executes a subshell where the command `set str=%str:~0,{the value of L}%` is executed.

But please note that not all filenames have a 3-character extension; the `for` modifiers are a better bet for that application. This method is a general-purpose `get the first L characters of a string` where `L`'s instantaneous value is required.